# Any performance advantage in copying the session to a variable?

Tags: php, web-applications

I have a fair number of items in a session, and I am wondering if there are any advantages to copying the session variable to a normal php variable (in order to close the session file as quickly as possible) and then do any calls from there. Something like:

```
session_start();
$copiedSession = $_SESSION;
session_write_close();
if (isset($copiedSessionData['foo'])){
    ...
}
...
```

1. I am looking for ways to test performance on this.
2. Does it make sense to do so?
3. Is there a break-even point where it helps / doesn't help?

Comment: Why the downvote? I can't learn from a mistake unless I know what is it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My PHP experience is very rusty, but in the example you provided, aren't you just creating a reference variable pointing to the session?  In other words,

```
$copiedSession = $_SESSION;
```

doesn't give you a "copy" of the session, but just a second variable from which you can reach it.

You want a deep copy.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
    $copiedSession[$key] = $value
```

I think that is what you want.

As for better performance, I suspect not.  It depends on whether $_SESSION is a pure associative array or if it is a special file-backed map that reads/writes through in real-time.

Judging by the PHP manual's SessionHandler interface, whose read/write methods take a session id and session array, I suspect that $_SESSION is a plain old array which comes from SessionHandler::read and gets passed back to SessionHandler::write.

However, to be absolutely sure, the best way is simply to test it.

You could do reading and writing in a loop say 10,000 times against the $_SESSION variable directly and measure min, max and mean execution time.  Then do the same thing against a copy (using the code I gave you above, not the reference pointer code) and compare the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you want a reference, it would be $copiedSession = &$_SESSION. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php.  I like your idea on the performance testing. If anyone else is looking for ways to implement something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php

Comment: @Cymbals PHP uses copy-on-write, so `$copiedSession = $_SESSION` isn't actually a copy; they really are pointing at the same data structure until one of them changes - _if_ Brandon is correct and it really is just an array.  If it's a special object, I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to do this when your storage engine is the file system and you have multiple scripts accessing the same session data. (ex: ajax calls). The file containing the session data will be locked until the first script ends execution and this can lead to performance issues.
You can find a detailed explanation [here](http://blog.zitec.com/2013/hidden-issues-with-php-sessions/)

Comment: That is a good thing to keep in mind.